# Remarkable tablet: Convert text file into notebook page

Tags: linux, text-processing, conversion

I am using the Remarkable 2 tablet with its note-taking functionality. I can scribble new notebook pages or annotate pdf-documents with the tools on it. I would, however, like to import existing text files (mainly txt) that I can then treat as if I had scribbled them (cut parts, move them around, erase single words, etc.).

Is there a conversion tool for Remarkable files that can convert text files into the format Remarkable uses for its notebook pages? Or could I batch-modify my text files so that Remarkable reads one as notebook page?

Comment: The only think I can think of off the top of my head is converting a text to an image which you could use as a _template_ (i. e. "paper" background); converting to the Remarkable penstroke-aware vector format would I suspect be a much heavier lift

Comment: Good thinking, but templates are fixed and not available to tools such as eraser and selector. I would just get static text in the background.

Comment: Could I get Remarkable to read each character in a text file as a single penstroke?

Comment: There is an excellent write-up on the file format here: https://plasma.ninja/blog/devices/remarkable/binary/format/2017/12/26/reMarkable-lines-file-format.html  Converting text to "lines" should be _doable_ but it would be a very heavy lift.  I am not aware of any existing tools to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I have done some digging, and have found [this project](https://github.com/bsdz/remarkable-layers) on GitHub which will convert an SVG file into the reMarkable file format.

Comment: This makes the conversion from text file to the Remarkable file format at least doable. Thanks for your research!

Comment: And now I need a tool that can batch-convert txt files to svg. Did you come across one?

Comment: That would be a different question.  But it might be easier to convert text to PDF, which that tool can then convert to SVGs and then reMarkable files.  Just "print" your text files to PDF files, and convert to your heart's content.  How to print to PDF would be beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I googled two conversion steps: From txt to pdf and then from pdf to svg. Both steps are possible with simple Linux command line tools. I think this will amount to a solution to my question. Thank you very much!